# utf-8 encoded page not rendering special characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

On this page (WP) http://jamiestclair.com/band/ the charset is UTF-8, but the special characters in names such as Kai Brückner, and Kai Schönberg are showing up as
Kai Sch�nberg
A utf-8 encoding should take care of that....

Header is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any help appreciated.

OK ----- here is all the relevant info. It's true the problem disappeared because I didn't know if anybody was going to answer this post, and I'm under a time constraint. So I fixed the special characters a different way, ie:  spelling out the name Schönberg this way: Sch-&-ouml-;nberg (spaces not included).

It is now returned to the special characters, and they are now not rendering. The Doc type and charset is now this:
 

 -- as opposed to being set at charset=utf-8

The odd thing is it is a Wordpress produced page. The problem with the characters not rendering is in the .php file that is producing the page. The exact same names are below in the body of the text which is in the db - and they are rendering correctly. It is just the characters in the HTML on the .php template page which is not rendering.

If that's not enuf information, tell me what else you need, and I'll include it. It's the latest v. of WP.

Comment: Does this data come from any database? From my experience it's usually problem with a db encoding.

Comment: A question should contain sufficient information for reconstructing the problem, including a relevant piece of content and HTML code. A link to a live page is *not* enough; the question loses all meaning t future visitors as soon as the live page has been fixed.

Comment: Not reproduceable. The live page mentioned has the names correctly shown in Firefox, Chrome, IE.

Comment: The page header showing the relevant charset encoding is provided, anything else in particular needed, I'll send it along. The page is back to original now.... The problem seems to be stemming from the HTML hardcoded on the php template page. It does not render correctly. Those are the names in the upper right corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of "UTF-8" "iso-8859-1". It should work now.

Comment: Here's the really odd thing: the home page, http://jamiestclair.com , has exactly the same doc type and charset encoding, utf-8. It also has HTML hardcoded special characters like ü and ö -- and they are rendering perfectly. No problem.